# Is it possible to run arbitrary queries with Linq to SQL? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

How would I write the following query using Linq to SQL?

```
UPDATE [TB_EXAMPLE] SET [COLUMN1] = 1
```

(My actual goal is more complex than this)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DataContext class has two query methods, ExecuteCommand, and ExecuteQuery.

The ExecuteQuery method returns LINQ to SQL Entities, so you need to pass a type to it:

```
[VB.Net]
MyDataContext.ExecuteQuery(Of Product)("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS")

[C#]
MyDataContext.ExecuteQuery<Product>("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS");
```

However, the ExecuteCommand doesn't need a type, you'd use this method for your UPDATE query Because you only need a String to write the query, you can use reflection to make a really generic UPDATE method for your DAL.

```
MyDataContext.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Products WHERE ProductID = {0}",1)
```

or

```
MyDataContext.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Products WHERE ProductID = 1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) has an [ExecuteCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) method that will allow you to execute arbitrary (hopefully, parameterized) SQL.

Quoting from the remarks on the DataContext link above:

> This method is a pass-through
>   mechanism for cases where LINQ to SQL
>   does not adequately provide for a
>   particular scenario.
>
> The syntax for the command is almost
>   the same as the syntax used to create
>   an ADO.NET DataCommand. The only
>   difference is in how the parameters
>   are specified. Specifically, you
>   specify parameters by enclosing them
>   in braces ({…}) and enumerate them
>   starting from 0. The parameter is
>   associated with the equally numbered
>   object in the parameters array.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var TB_EXAMPLE ex dbDataContext.TB_EXAMPLES)
{
   ex.COLUMN1 = 1;
}

dbDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: This method, while it will work, will be painfully slow. Each "UPDATE..." will be turned into its own statement and sent to the server in a batch. Calling ExecuteCommand() will execute much more quickly on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a DataContext connection, you can use the ExecuteCommand method of a DataContext object to execute SQL commands that do not return objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386906.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
var row = (from t in dataContext.table
            where t.id==1
            select t).Single();
row.columnName = 1;
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

edt, oops to slow ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the object directly then call save changes.

```
using (var ctx = new MyDataContext())
{
  var customer = ctx.Customers.First();
  customer.Name = "New Name";
  ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you're looking to do this is and actual SQL command then Scott Guthrie has a great post that demonstrates using the ExecuteQuery and ExecuteCommand methods at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx