# How to turn off triggers while using LinqToSQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, triggers

I have DB table with update trigger (to track history of changes). I want to use LinqToSql to do large changes on that table. But to do that fast I have to: turn off trigger, make changes and turn on trigger.
Is there any way to enable/disable triggers using LinqToSql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would have to use the following from [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748.aspx)

DISABLE TRIGGER { [ schema_name . ] trigger_name [ ,...n ] | ALL }
ON { object_name | DATABASE | ALL SERVER } [ ; ]

see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668024/is-it-possible-to-run-arbitrary-queries-with-linq-to-sql-c) on how to execute the above syntax (or any sql) via the DataContext

Comment: I know how to do that in sql:) But I don't want to do that in SQL Server Management studio.